Azure Python SDK - how can I know the latest API version for a resource ID?
I'm using the python Azure SDK, and for things like subnets, ipConfiguration objects will have a generic resource ID for the attached device - sometimes it's a NIC, or a PEP or something else. I know I can use the azure-mgmt-resources.ResourceManagementClient to get a generic resource object for one of these, BUT it requires an api_version which must be a valid version for the specific type of object!
Is there an API somewhere in the SDK to find these? e.g. API version for "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints" is "2024-01-01"
I have a lookup table for ones I use commonly, but it feels dirty.

To get latest API version of resource provider via Azure Python SDK, make use of below sample python code:
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient

tenant_id = 'tenantId'
client_id = 'appId'
client_secret = 'secret'

subscription_id = 'subId'

credentials = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)
resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)

provider_namespace = 'Microsoft.Network'
resource_type_name = 'privateEndpoints'

provider = resource_client.providers.get(provider_namespace)

resource_type = next(rt for rt in provider.resource_types if rt.resource_type == resource_type_name)
api_versions = resource_type.api_versions

latest_api_version = api_versions[0]  

print(f"The latest API version for {provider_namespace}/{resource_type_name} is: {latest_api_version}")

Response:

You can replace resource_type_name value accordingly based on your requirement to get latest API versions of those.
In my case, I used client credentials flow for authentication by granting Reader access to service principal under subscription level.

AAaah! Awesome, I would never have guessed it was called a Provider. Thanks!

@AnotherHowie Glad to be of help : )
